# How to extract integer and decimal numbers in PHP string correctly?

Tags: php

I have a string in PHP where I want to extract only integer and decimal numbers, this is an example:

```
<?php 

$string = 'María vive en un pueblo de 25 957 habitantes y cobra 1859 euros al mes. OJO: no sé si os habéis fijado, pero los números del último ejemplo 
no llevan un punto o una coma separando los millares (25.957 o 1.859). Sé que resulta extraño, pero la nueva normativa de la R.A.E. 
dice que los números de cuatro cifras NO llevarán separación (1859) y los números de cinco cifras o más NO llevarán ni puntos ni comas, 
sino una separación (25 957 o 1 343 392). El 94% de los niños ha traído los deberes hechos. He pagado $50,95 dólares.';

?>
```

In this case I try to get numbers using this line:

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.,]/', ' ', $string);
```

But the problem is the result is:

```
25 957 1859 . , 25.957 1.859 . , . . . 1859 , 25 957 1 343 392 . 94 . 50,95 .
```

And I want to get this result:

```
25 957 1859 25.957 1.859 1859 25 957 1 343 392 94 50,95
```

How can I fix it?

I'd like your help.

Comment: If it's possible I want to consider those details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a `.` for thousands and a `,` for decimals, and it looks like your text is intended for humans so there will always be a number immediately before a `.` and `,`.

So what you want is 1 or more numbers, followed by 0 or more thousand-groups (a `.` followed by 3 more numbers), optionally followed by exactly one `,` and one or more numbers.

```
One or more numbers: [0-9]+
0 or more thousand-groups: (\.[0-9]{3})*
Optionally a `,` and one or more numbers: (,[0-9]+)?
```

Combined: `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]+)?`

```
$string = 'María vive en un pueblo de 25 957 habitantes y cobra 1859 euros al mes. OJO: no sé si os habéis fijado, pero los números del último ejemplo 
no llevan un punto o una coma separando los millares (25.957 o 1.859). Sé que resulta extraño, pero la nueva normativa de la R.A.E. 
dice que los números de cuatro cifras NO llevarán separación (1859) y los números de cinco cifras o más NO llevarán ni puntos ni comas, 
sino una separación (25 957 o 1 343 392). El 94% de los niños ha traído los deberes hechos. He pagado $50,95 dólares.';

$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{3})*(,[0-9]+)?/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 25
    [1] => 957
    [2] => 1859
    [3] => 25.957
    [4] => 1.859
    [5] => 1859
    [6] => 25
    [7] => 957
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 343
    [10] => 392
    [11] => 94
    [12] => 50,95
)
*/
```

Comment: @user3783243 yes, my expression is *only* using a `,` as a decimal separator. It is using a `.` for a thousand separator. The given text does not have any numbers with a `,` as a thousand separator (although it does have numbers with a space as a thousand separator, but that wasn't part of what OP wanted).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works great, I just needed to add an `implode()` function, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression:

```
(\d*\.)?\d+
```

**NOTE**
This exp will match `25 957` like 2 matches (for the space between numbers).

Comment: what you mean? I did not understand

Comment: according to the first post it is exactly what he wanted to do

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most elegant way to do it but you could use two preg_replace functions based on your first REGEX and remove the decimals without any numbers wrapped around them like so :

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.,]+/', ' ', $string);
$decimals = preg_replace('/([^0-9][\.,])/', '', $numbers);
var_dump($decimals); // string(56) " 25 957 1859 25.957 1.859 1859 25 957 1 343 392 94 50,95"
```

Live example here : https://3v4l.org/9aUCt